# WSO2 Data services server Input and Output mapping for Integer type

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using WSO2 DSS 3.2.2 connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database. I have a sql query that takes in an int input. The input mapping allows for "Integer" type mapping. In the output mapping to the SQL resultset, we are mapping this same field (the column is returned in the resultset) also to type "Integer". Once the Data Service is saved/compiled, the wsdl maps the input paramater to xs:int and the output parameter to xs:integer. Is it possible to map the field to xs:int in DSS? Why does DSS map integer to xs:integer?

thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can change `integer` to `int` as given below.

1. Go to service dashboard of your service. Then click on "Edit Data Service (XML Edit)" hyperlink as shown below.
   [image]
2. When your data service's XML configuration is loaded, please change `integer` to `int` as shown below.
   [image]
3. Next, save your changes and allow service deploy again. Once, it is redeployed, go to WSDL file and you will able to see that `integer` has been changed to `int`